# How Can I Expose or Limit Commands via Group Membership (e.g.: RBAC)?

Tags: c#, powershell, rbac

I have PowerShell commands that I've written and rather than reinventing the wheel, I want to consume RBAC as a viable means to expose the commands to users when they load the assemblies in PowerShell (via Import-Module).

In conducting my search in (insert your favourite search engine here), I've come across things that are far-out in left field, like ACEs/ACLs. The closest that I found was [JEA](https://github.com/PowerShell/JEA) but this looks to be specific for remoting; which defeats the purpose, since the module would be loaded locally.

I saw there was a way to do group membership verification by a SQL table but that would require standing-up the server/database/table and defeats the purpose of wanting to consume resources that already exist.

I've checked out [PSPrinicpal.IsInRole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.remoting.psprincipal.isinrole?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [GenericPrincipal.IsInRole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.isinrole?view=netframework-4.7.2) but these require access/use inside of a namespace/class and, thus, aren't sufficient for what I'm trying to do; which is to prevent [a] specific command[s] from being available on "Import-Module", if the user doesn't belong to 'x' group; which I believe would need to be done on decoration of the class, itself?

```
namespace ExamplePowerShell
{
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.ServiceModel;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RestartRemoteServer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    [SOMETHING SHOULD GO HERE?]
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Restart, "RemoteServer")]
    public class RestartRemoteServer : Cmdlet
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

**Ask:** Is there a way to consume RBAC, without having to reinvent the entire premise from scratch?

Currently, all commands are available to anyone who loads the module and, rather than creating a separate module (which isn't any form of security if a user can find the other module), I want to ensure that no one else can run the commands in question without the appropriate group memberships.

**Goal:** To limit commandlet availability by group membership (or lack thereof), when the assembly is imported into the local PowerShell session.

**(Concept) Example:** A commandlet, "Restart-RemoteServer", should only be available to be run by individuals in the "DevOps" group and not be available to anyone with RDP permission to the machine, as anyone can import the module into PowerShell (or it could be loaded by default via PowerShell profiles).

Edit: Found an example that uses [OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/webservices/role-based-authorization-configuration-schema) but I would prefer to depend on AD.

Comment: Instead of obscurely trying to hide the cmdlets why not just return a proper error if you lack the sufficient permissions to use them? With your example you'd implement that check within `Restart-RemoteServer`.

Comment: In RBAC, the command isn't just *hidden*, the caller is disallowed from running it (assuming no permissions), if they try to call it by loading the assembly directly. An example of this from Exchange would be [Search-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#description).

Why should I expose a command that the users should not be able to run, in the first place, if the RBAC structure is already in place and used by multiple products (e.g.: Exchange, SharePoint, SfB, etc.)?

Comment: Your stated goal is limit the availability which I read as not letting it show up. For your example at least Exchange always relies on a remote connection even on a local server. Actively checking for permissions within your cmdlet allows you to make sure it's not run from another source. PowerShell session management would probably be what you're looking for and could be sufficient depending on how your setup looks.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Limit the permissions of your users.** They should not be able to do the actions themselves. This should be primary since generally nothing stops users write their own scripts/modules to do what yours do.

   In your example, users with the incorrect permissions should not have shutdown or restart permissions on the remote servers, much less access to your module. Your module should just be doing error catching on the permissions side.
2. **Split the commands into different module files.** Then set read permissions on the module files using your AD groups
3. **Query AD within your cmdlet.** For example in powershell:

   `((Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $env:username | where {$_.name -like "Domain Users"}) -like (get-adgroup "Domain Users"))`
4. **JEA.** Like you've already mentioned, you can limit access by only allowing your users to be active within locked-down sessions (these sessions can be local).